# cakephp finding multiple images and displaying them (possibly outside webroot?)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am currently trying to build a cakephp app that will list items from a database, and there is a field in the database named picture. This picture field contains a string which is the primary picture, so for example ABCD, and then in the images folder this is ABCD.jpg

However there is usually various extra pictures for this particular item, which may be named ABCD1 or ABCD_2 or some other such variating suffix. I had previously written some script in php which used a glob function and counted the files and outputted them.

I am seriously struggling to do this in cakephp, at the moment there is several thousand images stored in the webroot of the server in /images and I understand that cake will be looking in the webroot of the app like /app/webroot, so is it possible to view their original location? or must they be moved...

I have read a little about the file and folder classes but I am struggling to comprehend them, not sure if my brains failed me here or if this is actually a difficult concept..

my question is how would I find any files that begin with this prefix in the picture field after selecting by the id of the item, to then display all those that match for that particular item?

thanks for your help!

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Are you trying to use the cakephp html helper method like $html->image()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a real answer to your question but you should start making a database relationship with your pics.

Check out [`hasMany`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1043/hasMany) to make a relationship between your `Article` (or whatever it is) and the `Picture` models. Now you will not have to look for each filename, as you'll have it in your database.

Comment: thanks for the reply metrobalderas, I have implemented this now, and using the meioupload behaviour have successfully solved this issue (although I have implemented the glob function with a foreach in order to stop the gap until all pictures are re-added. If possible, could you help me with my other question? relating to related data and setting a data field to a value? many thanks again!